# WSO2 Governance Registry - Adding Notification for Service

Tags: java, notifications, registry, apache-axis, wso2

I am following the example listed in this [**link**](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Notification+E-mail+Customization+Sample) to add custom email notifications.

In my maven project '*RegistryService*': I created the EmailTransformHandler and used maven to create the *RegistryService-0.1.jar*. I also modified the `GREG_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` by adding the handler:

```
<handler name="EmailTransformHandler"
                 class="com.registration.example.service.EmailTransformHandler"/>
```

and dropped the RegistryService-0.1.jar in `GREG_HOME/repository/components/dropins`

```
package com.registration.example.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.xpath.AXIOMXPath;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.engine.Handler;
import org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler;

public class EmailTransformHandler extends AbstractHandler implements Handler {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
        if (msgContext.getTo() != null && msgContext.getTo().getAddress().startsWith("mailto:")) {
            try {
                SOAPEnvelope env = msgContext.getEnvelope();
                AXIOMXPath xPath = new AXIOMXPath("//ns:text");
                xPath.addNamespace("ns", "registry_example");
                OMElement element = (OMElement) ((ArrayList) xPath.evaluate(env)).get(0);
                element.setText(element.getText().replace("--", "This message intercepted by Terminator"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
    }

}
```

When I go to the GREG_HOME/bin and start the server I get following exception:

```
2013-02-08 12:05:00,952] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from GREG_HOME/wso2/wso2greg-4.5.3/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: com.registration.example.service.EmailTransformHandler
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.loadHandler(Utils.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processPhaseList(AxisConfigBuilder.java:549)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processPhaseOrders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:150)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.registration.example.service.EmailTransformHandler
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.loadHandler(Utils.java:116)
    ... 13 more
```

What configuration am I missing? Googling about this error does not yield any relevant results( except some Russian forums which do not help me much). I even tried adding the jar via WSO2 Management Console as an extension, but I still get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, your RegistryService-0.1.jar is not set properly to the class path.
If the jar file is not an OSGI bundle that jar file should be drop in to the "GREG_HOME/repository/components/lib" directory.

-Ajith